# Unable to shut down: failed to execute child process "lubuntu-logout" (no such file or directory)

Tags: lubuntu, uninstall

I am unable to shut down after i uninstalled many programs in lubuntu using software center. The error message that I get is:

```
 Failed to execute child process "lubuntu-logout" (no such file or directory).
```

Answer (score 0):

I know is too late, but I encountered the same problem today, I was installing Lubuntu and removing Xubuntu, both from terminal.

Just reinstall Lubuntu Desktop in order to reinstall (or repair) the desktop enviroment

sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop

Regards,